# Simple Date Format is throwing parse exception for what seems to be valid to me

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Why this line

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse("2016-09-19T17:30:48.743Z")
```

is throwing parse exception ?

Comment: Side note: consider to use the new Date and Time API.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2016-09-19T17:30:48.743Z");` Try using this way.

Comment: Your date string should not have "Z" in it, but should have a time zone value, like "-0700" or "PDT", for instance:
`f2.parse("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235PDT");` or `f2.parse("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700");`

Comment: This should help you if you are on Java 7 or later: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` - using pattern symbol X which can interprete the literal "Z" as UTC+00:00.